# Send Image to Server Nodejs

Tags: node.js, android-studio, retrofit, multer

I want to pass an image from the app to the server. But when I open the picture folder, no image found. I think the image able to send to the server but cannot store the image to the picture folder. I hope you guys can help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance

**Project Structure**

> ```
> |
> |-db
> |-node_modules
> |-app.js
> |-picture
> |-routes
>     |-perkhidmatan_rumput
>         |-rumput.js
> ```

**rumput.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null,'../../picture')
     },
     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
     }
   })


router.post('/api/PostPemantauanPerkhidmatanPotingRumput/:zon/:syarikat/:alamat_syarikat/'+
          ':nama_penyelia/:taman/:bulan/:tahun/:masa/:timeAMPM/:pusingan/:status/:catatan/:state/'+
          ':entryOperator', upload.single('image'),(req,res,next) =>{
          console.log(req.file)


})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

destination :

```
   cb(null,'../../../picture')
```

and filename will be :

```
let path = require('path');

cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname))
```

Comment: if your code is correct , the file must be stored somewhere in project

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve the problem.

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null,'picture/')
     },
     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, file.originalname)
     }
   })
var upload = multer({ storage })
```